# Feeding MediaPlayer with dynamic file

Tags: android, audio

Good day,
I have a small app, it has one button.
Whenever I press the button it makes sound using the MediaPlayer.
The issue is that I can't find how to make same mediaplayer to play other sounds,

For example:
I have list of 10 sounds, whenever I click on my button it randomly picks number from 1 to 10, afterwards it takes corresponding sound where randomly generated number is the position in the list and plays it.

The problem is what should I feed my MediaPlayer with in the bold area?
MediaPlayer mpfn = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),**R.raw.number1**);

I'm new to android, and sorry in advance in case my question hurt your feelings.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the media files located?

Comment: same as the example, raw folder, they are already present in the project (local)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the media files are stored in raw folder, you can play the songs in random this way:

First generate random number using `Math.random()` . Then play the corresponding music, this way:

```
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = ran.nextInt(3);
    if(x==0)
    {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fst);
    }
    else if(x==1)
    {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sec);
    }
    else if(x==2)
    {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.thd);
    }
    length = 0;
    try{mPlayer.prepare();}catch (Exception e){}
```

This shows how you can play randomly from 3 media files, the process for 10 files is no different. once its ready, you can play it using : `mPlayer.start();`

Comment: It's working, thank you. I was wondering if there is a way to replace the media file with variable?

Comment: you mean a variable for `R.raw.thd`  ?

Comment: Yes, so I would be able to insert there any other file in run-time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182525/android-get-r-raw-from-variable see this

Answer (score 0):

At last I can answer this question myself. 
This was very simple to achieve, I've made string-array and stored all my sounds there in my own order. So whenever I got my random number I've been just picking this number and used it as item index in that string array.